# how to open amazon pay using a deeplink?

Tags: react-native, upi, amazon-pay, react-native-deep-linking

i am working on a RN app, where i need to open open UPI apps for collecting money. **PhonePe**, **Google Pay**, **Paytm** work just fine, i am struggling with **amazonpay**.
i have tried a few example mentioned below it opens amazon app but not amazon pay screen

`amazonToAlipay://upi/pay?pa=your@vpa&pn=YourName&tn=Note&am=1&cu=INR`

`amazonToAlipay://pay?pa=your@vpa&pn=YourName&tn=Note&am=1&cu=INR`

Comment: I am pretty sure, that Amazon Pay does not allow collecting money through a simple deep link

Comment: Hi Manjunath, Amazon Pay is the externalization of payments outside of the Amazon app, so you won't need to go down that path.  Instead you just need to leverage the Amazon Pay libraries to launch into the proper authentication flow.  If you're working on a native mobile app, we recommend using secured web views.  This documentation should help you with the configuration of the Amazon Pay button to launch that flow - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-checkout/add-the-amazon-pay-button.html